# Create a unique constraint on conflict replace

Tags: android, sqlite

```
Android Studio 0.8.11
```

Hello,

I have the following unique constraint on the FEED_NUMBER column. So when I get new records that need to be inserted, I will just replace the records with the same FEED_NUMBER. However, when the insert runs it always adds the new records and ignoring the contraint. Have I done something incorrect here?

Here is my onCreate:

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
         String sql = "create table " + FottContract.TABLE
                + "(" + FottContract.Column.ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                 + FottContract.Column.FEED_NUMBER + " text, "
                 + FottContract.Column.TITLE + " text, "
                 + FottContract.Column.DESCRIPTION + " text, "
                 + FottContract.Column.IMAGE + " text, "
                 + "unique (" + FottContract.Column.FEED_NUMBER + ") on conflict replace" + ")";

        db.execSQL(sql);
    }
```

And this is how I insert:

```
 private void saveToSQLite() {
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

        /* For each item in the memory database insert into sqlite */
        for (int i = 0; i < mNewsFeedDB.size(); i++) {
            contentValues.put(FottContract.Column.FEED_NUMBER, mNewsFeedDB.get(i).getId());
            contentValues.put(FottContract.Column.TITLE, mNewsFeedDB.get(i).getTitle());
            contentValues.put(FottContract.Column.DESCRIPTION, mNewsFeedDB.get(i).getDescription());
            contentValues.put(FottContract.Column.IMAGE, mNewsFeedDB.get(i).getImage());

            /* Insert it */
            long row = mDb.insert(FottContract.TABLE, null, contentValues);
        }
    }
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Have you uninstalled your app after modifying the schema in `onCreate()`?

Comment: Yes, I have done that many times. I run the app and I get a fresh feed. In the onPause I save it to sqlite. When I restart the App I get another fresh feed. However, some of the feeds could have the same feed_number, I just want to replace those rows if they have a duplicated feed_number.

Comment: Its working fine in SQLite Manager with your give query.

Comment: But in case of same id with white space taking same value again. Can you check mNewsFeedDB.get(i).getId() has white space or not.

Comment: Yes, the code provided in the question is correct and should work as intended, although the "FEED_NUMBER" column should probably have a type affinity of integer instead of text. The bug has to be somewhere in the implementation.

Comment: This question might be silly, but have you verified whether `mNewsFeedDB.get(i).getId()` is returning duplicate ids? If possible can you share snapshot of sqlite table content or else Can you log the `mNewsFeedDB.get(i).getId()` and share the logcat?

Comment: before inserting you have to check the feed number is available or not in database,if it is available you should go for Update query else go for insert query.

Comment: I've just run a little test using your code and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT with solution:**
This problem annoyed me so I decided to create a little test project with the same code as in the question. So the first thing to notice is that the UNIQUE constraint is respected. There is only one row in the database with a given FeedNumber. However the ID of this row changes with every INSERT on count of the ON CONFLICT REPLACE on the UNIQUE constraint (the existing row gets deleted and replaced with the new row) and AUTOINCREMENT on the ID column (sets ID to highest ID+1).

Secondly I tried to insert with an existing ID, which of course failed, since you can't insert two rows with the same PRIMARY ID.

So the solution is to first check if the row exists (try to insert on id) and if it fails (ie row == -1) use the update method instead. This obviously assumes that you actually get the correct row id from the `mNewsFeedDB.get(i).getId()` method.

[Here is a link to my test project if anyone is interested in how I tested it.](https://github.com/Qw4z1/SQLitetest) Not the prettiest code, but it does the job.

---

I would like to see a print out of the table before and after the inserts, but this line strikes me as a little fishy:

> contentValues.put(FottContract.Column.FEED_NUMBER, mNewsFeedDB.get(i).getId());

What you are doing here is getting the ID of a given NewsFeedItem and assigning that value the FEED_NUMBER field but is the ID really the same as an existing feedNumber? If the ID if null for example SQLite will treat every FEED_NUMBER as unique (since different null values are treated as different values all together).

The other thing I have had issues with before is reusing the ContentValues object. You may need to create a new Contentvalues object for every pass in the for loop.

Comment: There is no problem with reusing a `ContentValues` object if all the values are reassigned for each key in each iteration. Altenatively, you can clear it after each usage. Creating a new instance of it on each iteration is not a good idea.

Comment: @corsair992 You are absolutely right. I must have made a mistake with the batch insert.

Comment: That's a nice technique for preserving the original row id, though that isn't always important. However, it is essential to do this inside a transaction in order to avoid race conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will try this first thing tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

Instead of `mDb.insert(..)` have you tried using the [insertWithConflict](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int%29) function? Something like:

```
/* Insert it*/
mDb.insertWithOnConflict(FottContract.TABLE, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
```

**PREVIOUS THOGUHTS**

(As pointed out by @corsair992 in comments, I think he is right in saying that the triggers are fired after deletion.)

Code seems to be fine but following might be the issue:

**Possible issue:**

- Are you using version `3.6.18` or above? I am supposing you would be since it was release in 2009. If you see the [release notes
  of SQL lite for version 3.6.18](http://www.sqlite.org/draft/changes.html#version_3_6_18), it says:

  > Delete triggers fire when rows are removed due to a REPLACE conflict resolution. **This feature is only enabled when recursive
  >   triggers are enabled.**
- Similar thing is mentioned if you read details of `REPLACE` on the
  [on Conflict Clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) page it says:

  > ... When the REPLACE conflict resolution strategy deletes rows in order to satisfy a constraint, delete triggers fire **if and only if
  >   recursive triggers are enabled**.

**Possible solution:**

It might be that `recursive_triggers` are disabled. You can enable recursive triggers by running the following SQL query:

```
PRAGMA recursive_triggers='ON'
```

You can execute the query in your code by using same [execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29) method that you are using in the sniplet given question. Checkout [SQLite fire DELETE trigger on a REPLACE](http://www.tristanwaddington.com/2012/06/sqlite-fire-delete-trigger-on-a-replac/) blog to see more. They guy who wrote the blog mentions that his team had similar issues. When they did a `REPLACE` into the table a duplicate entry would be entered into it.

So I am assuming the above might solve your problem. Hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Delete triggers are only fired (or not) _after_ the row has been deleted. The question seems to indicate that the original rows are not being deleted.

Comment: The default ON CONFLICT clause is already defined as REPLACE for the UNIQUE constraint of the relevant column in the CREATE TABLE statement - it shouldn't be necessary to explicitly specify it on each INSERT statement.

Comment: Well, all I'm asking is to check if it happens even when he/she uses `insertWithConflict` and ofcourse can remove the `on conflict replace` condition while creating tables. Different ways to achieve the same thing. So just trying to find where the issue might be. I think there is no harm in that.

Comment: OK, but you should probably post debugging suggestions in comments instead of as part of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when the insert runs it always adds the new records and
>   ignoring the contraint.

It sounds like you are observing the expected behavior of `REPLACE`. This conflict resolution algorithm will first delete any existing rows with the given `FEED_NUMBER` value before the insert occurs. The insert will then create a new row, with a new ID, with the specified feed number. After that insert, the returned row ID will be the only row in the table that contains that particular feed number.

You can only end up with multiple rows containing the same feed number if the value is `NULL`. From https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#uniqueconst:

> For the purposes of UNIQUE constraints, NULL values are considered distinct from all other values, including other NULLs.

Comment: The question seems to be pretty clear that the UNIQUE constraint is _not_ being observed.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the files generated from Green Dao (even if you are not using it generates valid sql lite code) I would use the following sintax:

To create the table

```
String constraint = ifNotExists? "IF NOT EXISTS ": "";
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + constraint + "'FottContract.TABLE' (" + //
            "'FottContract.Column.ID' INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ," + // 0: id
            "'FottContract.Column.FEED_NUMBER' TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE," + // 1: text
            "'FottContract.Column.TITLE' TEXT," + // 2: title
            "'FottContract.Column.DESCRIPTION' TEXT," + // 3: description
            "'FottContract.Column.ID' IMAGE,");"); // 4: image

    // Add Index
     // Add Index
    db.execSQL("CREATE INDEX " + constraint + "IDX_" + FottContract.TABLE + "_"+ FottContract.TABLE + "ON FottContract.TABLE" +
            " (FottContract.Column.FEED_NUMBER);");
```

To do the inserts

```
private void saveToSQLite() {
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();

    /* For each item in the memory database insert into sqlite */
    for (int i = 0; i < mNewsFeedDB.size(); i++) {
        contentValues.put(FottContract.Column.FEED_NUMBER, mNewsFeedDB.get(i).getId());
        contentValues.put(FottContract.Column.TITLE, mNewsFeedDB.get(i).getTitle());
        contentValues.put(FottContract.Column.DESCRIPTION, mNewsFeedDB.get(i).getDescription());
        contentValues.put(FottContract.Column.IMAGE, mNewsFeedDB.get(i).getImage());

        /* Insert it */
        long row = mDb.insertWithOnConflict(FottContract.TABLE, null, contentValues, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**EDIT** the awnser bellow is incorrect as pointed out by corsair992

Remove the `autoincrement` it fails because of `autoincrement` algorithm to avoid duplicated usages of the column value and since `ID` is a `primary key` you don't need it (see bellow the reason why)
as stated by the doc

```
If the AUTOINCREMENT keyword appears after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
that changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to prevent the reuse 
of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database. 
In other words, the purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs 
from previously deleted rows.
```

Since the `replace` works by deleting the previous row which the conflict occured then the `AUTOINCREMENT` algorithm would fail since the new insert would use one value previously used.

So thats a clear violation of what you intented by using `on replace` your basicly saying "ok i don't mind to reuse the values for this primary key" but with `AUTOINCREMENT` your are saying "I never want the same value to be reused for this primary key".

Note that you don't need to use `AUTOINCREMENT` since primary key is aliased to the `ROWID`

```
In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the ROWID 
(except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit signed integer.
```

https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: This answer is completely wrong and baseless. Quoting from your own posted link: "If a column has the type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT then a slightly different ROWID selection algorithm is used. The ROWID chosen for the new row is at least one larger than the largest ROWID that has ever before existed in that same table.". There is no issue or conflict with using REPLACE or any other constraint.

Comment: Ok this is how i like to see a down-vote, you're correct i skipped the fact that he isn't specifying the id when inserting will update awnser thanks for pointing out  @corsair992

Comment: The schema has the auto increment and the ID is the primary key. However, 'feed Number' might contain some updated information. So when the user fetches the new feed numbers will be inserted. And any duplicate feed number already in the database will be updated with new content. This is why I am trying to use the conflict with replace. If there is a better way I would be happy to try.

Comment: If the feed number is unique for one feed (maintains the same number for updated feed info)  you could use it as the primary key without autoincrement with on update replace and solve your issue

Comment: Note that Android apps usually (if using `CursorAdapter`) require a unique integer column named "id", which is usually defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. Of course, this column could also be populated manually to correspond to an external id. Alternatively, you can query "rowid" aliased to "id". This can be a good alternative solution to the method [posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26342206/3153792) by Qw4z1 for performing an "insert or replace" operation while retaining the original row ids.